# Django AttributeError: Form object has no attribute '_errors'

Tags: python, django

I'm overriding the init method in my form andthis is now returning an error *'TransactionForm' object has no attribute '_errors'*.

I would expect this to work because I've included super in my **init**, however perhaps I don't understand how to use this correctly. An explanation would be appreciated. What do I need to do to get form.errors working?

Full traceback

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in
>   inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\py\portfolio-project\myportfolio\views.py" in add_transaction
>     136.  return render(request, 'myportfolio/add_transaction.html', {'form': form})
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py"
>   in render
>     36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in
>   render_to_string
>     62.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     175.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     999.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_value_in_context
>     978.             value = str(value)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in 
>     371.     klass.**str** = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in **str**
>     136.         return self.as_table()
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in as_table
>     279.             errors_on_separate_row=False)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in
>   _html_output
>     196.         top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in
>   non_field_errors
>     305.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
>     173.         if self._errors is None:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /myportfolio/add_transaction/
>   Exception Value: 'TransactionForm' object has no attribute '_errors'

forms

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):     
    CHOICES = ((1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell'),)

    coin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Coin.objects.all()) 
    buysell = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)

    field_order = ['buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price']

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = {'buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price'}

    def __init__(self, coin_price = None, user = None, *args, **kwargs):

        if user:
            self.user = user
            qs_coin = Portfolio.objects.filter(user = self.user).values('coin').distinct()
            super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(self.user, *args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['coin'].queryset = qs_coin

        if coin_price:
            self.coin_price = coin_price
            super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(self.user, self.coin_price, *args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['price'] = self.coin_price
```

Views

```
def add_transaction(request):
    print(request.method)
    print("test1")

    print(request.GET)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.is_ajax():
            print("ajax test")

            data = {
                'test': "test1"
            }

            form = TransactionForm(request.GET, user = request.user, coin_price = GetCoin("Bitcoin").price)

            return JsonResponse(data)


    form = TransactionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("test2")
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("test3")
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/myportfolio/')
        else: 
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'myportfolio/add_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Form's superclass `__init__` method not called if `coin_price` and `user` not provided. That's why such form's attributes as `_errors` was not created. You need to rewrite form's `__init__` like this:

```
def __init__(self, coin_price = None, user = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.user = user
            qs_coin = Portfolio.objects.filter(user = self.user).values('coin').distinct()
            self.fields['coin'].queryset = qs_coin

        if coin_price:
            self.coin_price = coin_price
            self.fields['price'] = self.coin_price
```

To make `super.__init__()` called in any cases.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the bug, be careful when you are coding fast, the autofill of your debbuger might propose a view instead of a form due to naming similarities.

So just make sure that you are actually calling the form and not a view !!! took me half an hour to figure out ...